# Devise authentication with email as usual, but forcing the user to put a name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Well, to contextualize a bit, I want devise acts just like always, **the only difference being that when a user sign up, he have to put a name (and it doesn't have to be blank)**

What I have achieved is that when the user sign up he can put a name, the problem is that he can leave it blank and his name will be equal to `""`.

I did this with some help of what appears on [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) page, ie creating a migration to add the name column to the users table and putting the following in the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

But what is explained there later is not exactly what I want to do, I want the user to always sign in with his email (as devise already does by default), as I said, **the only thing I wish is that if anyone wants to sign up, he have to type some name, being this not blank**.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: what you need to do is to add validation for name to the `user` model. Validate the presence of name on a user

Comment: Well, that was the fastest solution ever, ty, btw, if you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is to add validation for name to the `user` model. Validate the presence of name on a user

So, in your user model:

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

with this, when a user submits a registration form with blank name, this validation will kick in, and prevent this user instance from being saved, while adding the `"name can't be blank"` error to the form.